# GLKMatrix4Multiply is broken

Tags: glkit

I have following method:

```
func printMatrix(m: GLKMatrix4) {
    var s = ""
    for i in 0...15 {
        s += "\(m[i]), "

        if (i + 1) % 4 == 0 {
            print(s)
            s = ""
        }
    }
    print("")
}
```

and some code below:

```
let a = GLKMatrix4Identity
self.printMatrix(a)

let b = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(3.0, 0.0, 0.0)
self.printMatrix(b)

let m = GLKMatrix4Multiply(a, b)
self.printMatrix(m)
```

Finally I see the result:

```
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 

1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 
3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 

1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 
0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0,
```

It seems like multiplying doesn't work properly. Does anyone can explain it or suggest any similar library for matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs only while testing with iOS simulator (I was testing code above with simulator). On real device GLKMatrix4Multiply works properly.